# Unable to pip install jq on Windows

Tags: python, jq, py-langchain, jsonloader

I wrote this code in Python(using Langchain) in order to load different types of documents and retrieve a proper ai answer related to a question asked before. It was working okay until I decided that I need to implement history, so that the AI Model have information it can relate to.
It throws an error saying 'pip install jq' but whenever I try to it does not work and prompts 'Failed to build jq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for jq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects'
I think it is not available for Windows, bc I have tried downloading it with winget, manually downloading jq file and setting a path, but I need to install it as a package, so that JSONLoader can call it on just 1 line. It needs to be  a JSON Loader since all the other document loaders are type Loader.

I am sending a list of messages(chat history) and in the PHP Laravel back-end I encode it into json using:

```
$jsonHistory = json_encode($request['chatHistory'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

After that I receive the chat history as a str in the Python back-end:

```
class Request(BaseModel):
        ai_input: str //these two are not important for that
        company: str //
        chatHistory: str

class AiModel:
 async def get_answer(request: Request):
 txt_loader = DirectoryLoader(f"{request.company}/", glob="**/*.txt", loader_cls=TextLoader)
        pdf_loader = DirectoryLoader(f"{request.company}/", glob="**/*.pdf", loader_cls=PyMuPDFLoader)
        csv_loader = DirectoryLoader(f"{request.company}/", glob="**/*.csv", loader_cls=CSVLoader)
        json_loader = JSONLoader(request.chatHistory, jq_schema='.input[]content')

loadersList = [txt_loader, pdf_loader, csv_loader, json_loader]
        index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders(loadersList)
        llm = ChatOpenAI
        if request.ai_input:
 query = request.ai_input 
         answer =  index.query(query, llm=llm)
return {"answer":answer}
```

Any ideas How can I proceed, so that I can load the json file with the rest of the docs?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/jq/ indeed lists only Linux and Mac as supported platforms. It seems unlikely that you could port it to Windows as a side project if you have not done such things before. The built-in JSON parser should produce a native Python data structure so you can pull out something like `[x['content'] for x in data['input']]` but it's not clear from your question how exactly these pieces fit together.

Comment: (Ultimately, my recommendation is always to get rid of Windows as soon as you can.)